# scipy.integrate.quad gives wrong result on large ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I am trying to integrate over the sum of two 'half' normal distributions. `scipy.integrate.quad` works fine when I try to integrate over a small range but returns 0 when I do it for large ranges. Here's the code:

```
mu1 = 0
mu2 = 0
std1 = 1
std2 = 1

def integral_fun(x):
    nor1 = 0.5 * ((1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * std1)) * (np.e ** ((-(x-mu1) ** 2) / (2 * std1 **2))))
    nor2 = 0.5 * ((1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * std2)) * (np.e ** ((-(x-mu2) ** 2) / (2 * std2 **2))))
    return nor1 + nor2


integrate.quad(integral_fun, -5, 5)
Out[54]: (0.9999994266968564, 8.668320228277793e-10)

integrate.quad(integral_fun, -10, 10)
Out[55]: (1.0000000000000002, 8.671029607900576e-10)

integrate.quad(integral_fun, -100000, 100000)
Out[56]: (0.0, 0.0)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: numerical integrals are approximated by a weighted sum of function values. If I had to guess I would say that the function values are all 0, because almost all points of the range have a density of (almost) 0.

Comment: it works though if the ranges are from `-inf` to `inf`

Comment: @ThePredator This is because in that case scipy will transform the integral into one over the range ``(0,1]`` with the transformation ``x = (1-t)/t``. This then well samples points near the origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason here is that your function is only very strongly peaked in a very small region of your integration region and is effectively zero everywhere else, `quad` never finds this peak and thus only see's the integrand being zero.

Since in this case you know where the peaks are, it would be reasonable to split the limits of the integration so that you consider the regions around the peaks separately.

To do this you can use the `points` argument in a slightly bastardized way to force `quad` to consider the peaks separately.

```
In [3]: integrate.quad(integral_fun, -100000, 100000, points=[-10,10])
Out[3]: (1.0000000000000002, 8.671029607900576e-10)
```