# scipy integrate.quad return an incorrect value

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

i use scipy integrate.quad to calc cdf of normal distribution:

```
def nor(delta, mu, x):
    return 1 / (math.sqrt(2 * math.pi) * delta) * np.exp(-np.square(x - mu) / (2 * np.square(delta)))


delta = 0.1
mu = 0
t = np.arange(4.0, 10.0, 1)
nor_int = lambda t: integrate.quad(lambda x: nor(delta, mu, x), -np.inf, t)
nor_int_vec = np.vectorize(nor_int)

s = nor_int_vec(t)
for i in zip(s[0],s[1]): 
    print i
```

while it print as follows:

```
(1.0000000000000002, 1.2506543424265854e-08)
(1.9563704110140217e-11, 3.5403445591955275e-11)
(1.0000000000001916, 1.2616577562700088e-08)
(1.0842532749783998e-34, 1.9621183122960244e-34)
(4.234531567162006e-09, 7.753407284370446e-09)
(1.0000000000001334, 1.757986959115912e-10)
```

for some x, it return a value approximate to zero, it should be return 1. 
can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.integrate.quad gives wrong result on large ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913664/scipy-integrate-quad-gives-wrong-result-on-large-ranges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same reason as in [why does quad return both zeros when integrating a simple Gaussian pdf at a very small variance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137244/why-does-quad-return-both-zeros-when-integrating-a-simple-gaussian-pdf-at-a-very) but seeing as I can't mark it as a duplicate, here goes:

You are integrating a function with tight localization (at scale delta) over a very large (in fact infinite) interval. The integration routine can simply miss the part of the interval where the function is substantially different from 0, judging it to be 0 instead. Some guidance is required. The parameter `points` can be used to this effect (see the linked question) but since `quad` over an infinite interval does not support it, the interval has to be manually split, like so:

```
for t in range(4, 10):
    int1 = integrate.quad(lambda x: nor(delta, mu, x), -np.inf, mu - 10*delta)[0] 
    int2 = integrate.quad(lambda x: nor(delta, mu, x), mu - 10*delta, t)[0] 
    print(int1 + int2)
```

This prints 1 or nearly 1 every time.  I picked `mu-10*delta` as a point to split on, figuring most of the function lies to the right of it, no matter what mu and delta are.

Notes:

1. Use `np.sqrt` etc; there is usually no reason for put `math` functions in NumPy code. The NumPy versions are available and are vectorized.
2. Applying `np.vectorize` to `quad` is not doing anything besides making the code longer and slightly harder to read. Use a normal Python loop or list comprehension. See [NumPy vectorization with integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223186/numpy-vectorization-with-integration)