# scipy.integrate.tplquad gives wrong result for integral over large volume

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I'm trying to integrate a function of 3 variables f(x,y,z) over all space.

When I integrate over a small volume, I get roughly the right result. However, when I increase the volume of integration, python says that the integral is zero.

I'm fairly confident that the issue here is that the function f is only non-zero in a small region of space, and tplquad dosen't sample over this region enough when the integration volume is large. I found an answer to a similar problem in 1D at this link; [scipy.integrate.quad gives wrong result on large ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913664/scipy-integrate-quad-gives-wrong-result-on-large-ranges). The solution in 1D was to pass an argument 'points' to scipy.integrate.quad, and this helped quad focus on the interval where the integral was non-zero.

**My question is; is there a similar argument to 'points' for tplquad? 
Or perhaps some other way I can instruct tplquad to focus on a particular region of space?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `tplquad` is just a wrapper over [`nquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad) which does not expose all of the options of the latter. Use `nquad`, which supports passing `points` to `quad` via `opts` parameter. A simple example, with the same points for all ranges:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import nquad
f = lambda x, y, z: np.exp(-x**2-y**2-z**2)
nquad(f, [[-150, 90], [-150, 90], [-150, 90]])[0]   # 2.260158041551299e-16, wrong
nquad(f, [[-150, 90], [-150, 90], [-150, 90]], opts={"points": [-5, 5]})[0]   # 5.568327996820292, correct
```

In general, `opts` can be a list of different options for different steps of multiple integration, and `points` can differ between them. They can also depend on other variables, like limits of integration can; see the example in the documentation.